# Unable to send SMS message in Android from variable

Tags: android, android-studio, smsmanager

When I use this code:

```
String numberToSendFor = "21987654321";
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(numberToSendFor, null, "Test Message", null, null);
```

The SMS Message is **sent normally** (and goes to sent messages list in my phone).

But, when I use this:

```
String numberToSendFor = "21987654321";
String messageToSend = "Test Message"; // store the message into a variable
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(numberToSendFor, null, messageToSend, null, null);
```

The message **don't is sent** and don't goes to sent messages list.

What should I do to send message from a variable?

Note: **I have the permission to send SMS** (AndroidManifest.xml).

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the permissions for sending an sms?

Comment: Yes, I do. The first example is sent normally.

Comment: does any exception appear? stacktrace?

Comment: None exception... :/ It shows as if the SMS was sent normally, but I don't receive it (and it doesn't go to sent messsage list).

Comment: puh very strange :/

Comment: What's your target API? This is a weird bug, I'm using practically the same code and my message is in the variable and it works :D It does send the message, but the message is **not** in sent messages.

Comment: Is "Test Message" the actual message you're sending? Are you sure you're not going over the character limit for a single-part message?

Comment: +Mike M. the message, when I put directly as parameter, is sent normally. But, when I put through a variable, isn't send.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part. I'm asking if "Test Message" is the actual, exact message you're sending. Also, it's `@` to ping a user, not `+`.

Comment: @Mike M. lol... Thanks. The actual message is "Mensagem de teste do sistema".

Comment: Well, I wouldn't think that would be over the limit, even if you are using characters that aren't in the default or 8-bit alphabets, but it might be worth it to try the `sendMultipartTextMessage()` method instead.

Comment: I think this question should have more upvotes because it is very strange :D

Comment: I got the same issue. Have you solved this question?

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I'm still got this error... :/

Comment: very unlikely. Are you sure this is the exact code you are using, in the exact same context both times?

Comment: I solved this. I pass message text through variable. Some times it will not send sms and also not store in message inbox. 

I Complete remove application, and remove also 1 SIM card from dual sim mobile. Now this is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the already existing intent provided by android

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "default content"); 
sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Also this requires permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This does not do the same thing the OP's code is doing. This opens another app to send the message. This also does not require the `SEND_SMS` permission.